# How to create a responsive grid in React Native?

Tags: css, react-native

[image]

How do I create a responsive layout similar to the Top Up Value shown in the image above?

What I have now is this:

[image]

How do i create a box that won't stretch its height? And how can I make sure that the boxes would wrap to next line like in the pic below

[image]

This is my code:

```
    topUpOptionsContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        marginVertical: 15,
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
    },

    topUpOptions: {
        padding: 10,
        borderColor: '#d1d7dc',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 10,
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: wp('25%')
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the code is working. Turns out the actual text has a `flex: 1` which causes it to stretch.